# Possible to get all Items from JList?

Tags: java, user-interface, selection, jlist

I know it is possible to get all selected Items from a JList with:

```
leftlist.getSelectedValues();
```

But is it possible to get all Items and not only the selected ones?

Comment: but how was the list populated???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getModel()` and `getSize()` to catch the length of the `JList`. Also you need a loop to iterate through the indexes to get elements(`getElementAt()`).

Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i< jList.getModel().getSize();i++){
    System.out.println(jList.getModel().getElementAt(i));
}
```

---

You are right, you can get selected values from `jList.getSelectedValues()`. Also it is possible to get multiple selected elements in `JList` by `jList.getSelectedValuesList()` or listen for events on the list's `ListSelectionModel`. Read the documentation for [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

[Multiple selection demo from oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/ListSelectionDemoProject/src/events/ListSelectionDemo.java).